# Handling the Tab Bar Controller View buttons and code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm developing an app for my thesis and I'm a little bit confused on what I should do here/where to write the code that I have and that worked before modifying these views.

Basically after the login process I only had a view (I was still testing at that time), now I made a Tab Bar Controller and 3 view under it. Problem is, the logout button I made for them is no longer working cause I don't know where to write the code for the Tab Bar Controller View...

For a normal view you just connect the swift file and it's done and dusted, you write everything you want in there and watch it work with the assistant view, but I'm not familiar with the Tab Bar Controller View...

In the photo I provided there is a logout button that is clicked, so you can see it better.

[Logout Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0FWa.jpg)

The code I used for the button when the view worked:

```
    @IBAction func bottoneLogout(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
        print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
    }

    }
```

I'm also trying to remove the "Back" button, I had the code for it and have the same question for where to place the code to get it working again:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Grafici"
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
```

App Structure: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KNOi.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a class to `UITabBarController`  like:

```swift
class MyTabbarController: UITabBarController {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Then set the class of the `UITabBarController` from the storyboard inspector, then try to put the logout logic in the custom class you created.

[image]

Note that depending on your view hierarchy, you should manage the navigation, that means if your `UITabBarController` is a child for `UINavigationController`, you can access the navigation controller from the tabbar reference: `tabbarController?.navigationController`

Comment: Hi and sorry for answering just now, is this a piece of code I should place in the appDelegate.swift?

Comment: No, just create a new swift file and put this code in it.

Comment: I'm adding a photo to the post, can you tell me if it's a good way of using the tab bar? Cause maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: It depends on the design you want to achieve, if you have a tabbar in your design you have to use UITabbarController, and looking at the photo, there is nothing wrong with the structure but I can see that the logout button is in the UITabbarController itself, so the action of the logout button should be written in the UITabbarController subclass.

Comment: I added a photo in my answer shows where you can set the custom class from the storyboard

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the answer. Should I place the code you made in a separated swift file or in the first page (where the navigation controller begins?

Comment: Update: this did work and actually in a perfect manner! Thank you so much! It's exactly what I wanted to achieve! Also, I cannot edit your answer, but the class should be UITabBarController, you missed a capital letter in "Bar". Have a great day!